# I have install mysql server version 5.7.9 but mysql json functions not working?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have install mysql server version 5.7.9 but mysql json functions not working like jsn_length(),jsn_merge()..etc.

I have created a table with one field.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( 
jdoc json DEFAULT NULL 
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

After insert data in this field with json format:
"{"name": "pankaj", "lname": "kumar"}"

then I execute this query

```
select jsn_length(jdoc) from t1
```

I am getting this type error in phpmyadmin:

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1305 - FUNCTION jsn_length does not exist

Comment: If you run "SELECT JSON_LENGTH('[1, 2, {"a": 3}]');" what do you get ?

Comment: If you got the value 3 then it is working :)
See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-attribute-functions.html#function_json-length

Comment: Can you give the exact call you do when you get '1305 - FUNCTION jsn_length does not exist'

Comment: okay but why i am getting error from table.. when i execute this query "select JSON_LENGTH(jdoc) from t1";

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a simplified version of your table and the exact query you are doing ? The more info the better

Comment: create table structure   "CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `jdoc` json DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;"

Comment: I have edited your question as per your comment

Comment: okay, how can we get results form t1 table  any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is syntax related.

Instead of :

```
select jsn_length(jdoc) from t1
```

Run :

```
select JSON_LENGTH(jdoc) from t1
```